# Multi property sort Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have objects that are in an array I'd like to sort

```
let person = Person()
person.isHome = true
person.firstname = "Foo"
person.surname = "Bar"
```

etc...

I fetch all the people

```
guard let allPeople = controller.fetchedObjects as? Array<Person> else { return }
```

Now I'd like to filter and sort

```
var homeArray = allPeople
        .filter { $0.isHome == true }
        .sort { $0.surname < $1.surname }
```

All fine... except, what if I want extra 'sort descriptors' like this...

```
var homeArray = allPeople
        .filter { $0.isHome == true }
        .sort { $0.surname < $1.surname }
        .sort { $0.firstname < $1.firstname }
        .sort { $0.isOut == true && $1.isOut == false }
```

I still want them ordered by surname, but I also want them sorted by first name after surname and injured above non injured... What is the syntax? I can't seem to find it anywhere... Do I have to go back to using NSArray?

Is it as simple as

```
.sort { ($0.isOut == true && $1.isOut == false) && ($0.firstname < $1.firstname) && ($0.surname < $1.surname)}
```

Comment: Change the `fetchRequest` of `NSFetchedResultsController` which is much more efficient than `manual` filtering / sorting

Comment: What if I can't change the FRC? I know that doesn't make a lot of sense, but the guys I'm working for a framework I have to work within... So I get allPeople and then I must filter and sort after fetching... It's not that there isn't a better way to do this... more that I need the syntax for sorting in this way but with multiple properties

Answer (score 1):

```
let new = [person,person1,person2,person3,person4]

var homeInArray = new
.filter { $0.isHome == true &&  $0.isInjured == true }
var homeNINArray = new
.filter { $0.isHome == true &&  $0.isInjured == false }


 var newHomeArray =    homeInArray.sort { $0.firstName < $1.firstName } + homeNINArray.sort { $0.firstName < $1.firstName }
```

Try it out this solution ...

Comment: Sorry if I confused things with the bool syntax (which might be wrong) I want to sort not only on bools, but multiple conditions.. I've added first name is as well

Comment: This is a fair answer to the exact problem I presented though so +1.. but isn't exactly what I need to know